# Error when including \usepackage{hyperref}

Tags: hyperref

I'm new to LaTeX and trying to use `hyperref`, and having trouble with `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

As recommended in posts, I included `\usepackage{hyperref}` as the last `\usepackage{}` instruction. No other problem when I comment out `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

I've successfully compiled the testams.tex document that came with the `hyperref` download from TUG and uses

```
\usepackage[%
  verbose,
  colorlinks=true,
  naturalnames=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
]{hyperref}
```

I am receiving this error:

```
!Latex Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section
```

This is my preamble and document structure:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}                 
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                 % Activate for for rotated page geometry

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[comma,authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}    % Activate to format captions
\captionsetup[table]{font=bf}   % Make table captions bold
%\usepackage[format=hang,font={small,bf}]{caption}  %Makes all captions bold

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{New Author}
\date{\today}              

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Begin}

\section{Continue}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \begin{center}
  \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    %table
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:first}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\newpage
\appendix
\chapter{App 1}
\section{App 1.1}
Lots of tables.

\pagebreak

\begin{singlespace}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{singlespace}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you get your `\subtitle` command from? Not that I think that's the problem, it's just that your example will get stuck there for me.

Comment: If you want to use the command `\subtitle` you have to use a KOMA-Script document class, where it is defined. For example, substitute `report` with `scrreprt`: `\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{scrreprt}`

Comment: Unrelated to your problems: you probably want to use `\centering` in tables and figures instead of `\being{center}` and `\end{center}`. (Also I personally like my `\label` directly after the `\caption`, but your preferences may vary. As long as it's after the caption.)

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please update your example to show the *real* error message and not `! Undefined control sequence` in line 22. Also post the *full* error message (e.g. from the `.log` file including the line number). If `\listfiles` is added at the begin of the TeX file, then LaTeX will print a version list at the end of the `.log` file (try pressing `q` for batch mode on the first error message to get a chance to reach `\end{document}`. If you are using older software, try updating your TeX distribution.

Comment: I'm sure there are _some_ packages on CTAN that you _haven't_ included **yet**. Please create a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5763) that demonstrates your problem. And please include only those packages in your document that you _know_ you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't give any errors, except the `\subtitle` command. Commenting it out will solve the problem.

CHeers!

Comment: Exactly correct for the code I gave.  My document had other code to format tables, etc. including a \newcommand{subtitle}(removed that cause using scrrprt). I discovered \DeclareOption{oneside}{\@twosidefalse \@mparswitchfalse} to be the conflict with \usepackage{hyperref}.  Took it out, and all looks good now.  Thank you for the help, and I hope my comment is useful for others.